# Many To Many Querying Tagging Objects

Tags: mysql

I have this database schema. I'm calling the stuff I'm tagging objects just for the sake of making it simple:

### Users

- user_id
- login

### User to Object table (many to many)

- user_id
- object_id

### Object table

- object_id
- object_stuff

### Object to tag with user_id table (many to many with extra column)

- user_id
- object_id
- tag_id

### Tag table

- tag_id
- tag_name

I have been using a query like this in order to get the objects of a particular user as well as the objects' tags (if the user tagged any). **If you think you can optimize this, feel free to let me know**.

```
@user_id = 'whatever user_id I want';
SELECT 
    o.object_id AS object_id,
    o.object_stuff AS object_stuff,
    IF (tags.tag_name IS NOT NULL, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name SEPARATOR '|'), 'N/A') AS tags
FROM  object_table AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN  obj_to_users_table AS o2u ON o.object_id = o2u.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN  users AS u ON u.user_id = o2u.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  obj_to_tag_users AS o2tu ON o.object_id = o2tu.object_id AND u.user_id = o2tu.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN  tags AS t ON t.tag_id = o2t.tag_id 
WHERE u.user_id = @user_id GROUP BY o.object_id
```

Which would yield results like this:

```
object_id     object_stuff        tags
1             stuff1...           tag1|tag2|tag3
2             stuff2...           tag4|tag6|tag1
3             stuff3...           tag7|tag2|tag5
```

My problem is that I would like to, for example, search for objects that are tagged as 'tag2' and I should get:

```
object_id     object_stuff        tags
1             stuff1...           tag1|tag2|tag3
3             stuff3...           tag4|tag2|tag1
```

But instead, I lose the other tags that accompany the object:

```
object_id     object_stuff        tags
1             stuff1...           tag2
3             stuff3...           tag2
```

**How do I modify my WHERE clause so that I can get the objects tagged as 'tag2' but also keeping the other tags the object has in the result set?**

```
... WHERE u.user_id = @user_id AND t.tag_name LIKE '%tag2%' ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, calculate the concatenated results.

Next, perform your search against those concatenated results to preserve the groupings of the tags:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        o.object_id AS object_id,
        o.object_stuff AS object_stuff,
        IF (tags.tag_name IS NOT NULL, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name SEPARATOR '|'), 'N/A') AS tags
    FROM  object_table AS o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  obj_to_users_table AS o2u 
        ON o.object_id = o2u.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  users AS u 
        ON u.user_id = o2u.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  obj_to_tag_users AS o2tu 
        ON o.object_id = o2tu.object_id AND u.user_id = o2tu.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  tags AS t ON t.tag_id = o2t.tag_id 
    WHERE u.user_id = @user_id 
    GROUP BY o.object_id
) sub
WHERE sub.tags LIKE '%tag2%'
```

**EDIT:**

---

Here's an example that uses an `EXISTS`.  I also switched the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s, since searching for a specific tag should eliminate any `objects` without `tags` anyways.

While this query looks more complicated, it should have a better chance of using any available indexes.

I had also mentioned doing the same type of query using an additional set of `INNER JOIN`s, but that one would look even more complex since you'd still have to use a sub-query to use `DISTINCT` to get rid any possible duplicates introduced by the additional `JOIN`s... so I'd suggest using `EXISTS` instead...

```
SELECT 
    o.object_id AS object_id,
    o.object_stuff AS object_stuff,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name SEPARATOR '|') AS tags
FROM  object_table AS o
INNER JOIN  obj_to_users_table AS o2u 
    ON o.object_id = o2u.object_id
INNER JOIN  users AS u 
    ON u.user_id = o2u.user_id 
INNER JOIN  obj_to_tag_users AS o2tu 
    ON o.object_id = o2tu.object_id AND u.user_id = o2tu.user_id
INNER JOIN tags AS t 
    ON t.tag_id = o2t.tag_id
WHERE 
    u.user_id = @user_id 
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tags AS targetTag
        WHERE 
            targetTag.tag_id = o2t.tag_id
            AND targetTag.tag_name = 'tag2'
    )
GROUP BY o.object_id
```

Comment: Oh cool that worked, thanks. Is a sub query the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: @rclai89 There's probably a few other ways to do this... you could perform the filtering before doing the `GROUP_CONCAT`, either by doing inner joins or with an `EXISTS`.  The query would probably look a little more complex with these methods, but it would also be able to make use of indexes, so it would likely perform better...

Comment: If it doesn't trouble you, would you show me what those alternative queries look like? Or perhaps show me guides for these kinds of queries to get started?